# Find Word Which comes first in php

Tags: php

I have 2 words like `%sku%` and `%any%` that will be used in the sites url structure.

This data will be saved in a database and I need to find out which comes first.

E.g.

In the below url `%sku%` comes first

`http://example.com/%sku%/product/%any%`

While in the below url `%any%` comes first

`http://example.com/%any%/product/%sku%`

Furthermore I cant be sure that the structure will be consistent it could be like any of the below:

> http://example.com/%sku%/product/%any%
>    http://example.com/%any%/product/%sku%
>    http://example.com/%any%/%sku%
>    http://example.com/product/%sku%
>    http://example.com/product/%any%

I want to check which comes first and which comes last.. but `%sku% and`%any%` are defined by me..  so i can be 100% sure that those tags are going to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `strpos`

something like:

```
$URL = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$posOfSku=strlen($URL);
$posOfAny=strlen($URL);

if(strpos($URL ,'%sku%') !== false) {
    $posOfSku = strpos($URL ,'%sku%');
}
if(strpos($URL ,'%any%') !== false) {
    $posOfAny= strpos($URL ,'%any%');
}

$result =  ($posOfAny < $posOfSku) ? 'any came 1st' : 'sku came 1st';
echo $result;
```

Comment: A few points. The answer doesn't display which comes last. It also requires excessive refactoring if there are more than arguments and they are anything other than `%sku%` or `%any%`.

Comment: that' just a prototype..you can use array and loop over it keeping the same logic and I think the OP would be able to do it himself... He just needed a direction here not the entire code and new requirements..

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for several of the uri requirements in the original question. If no `%any%` string is in the url, `$posOfAny` is equal to `0`. so the `$result` will be `'any came 1st'` even though it isn't in the uri string.

Comment: Now that's a valid point! Thanks for your suggestion. Fixed in update

Answer (score 3):

The following code will return the first and last occurring items from a designated `$attributes` array.

```
$string = 'http://example.com/%sku%/product/%any%';

// values to check for
$attributes = ['%sku%', '%any%'];

$results = array();
foreach($attributes as $attribute)
{
   // Get position of attribute in uri string
   $pos = strpos($string, $attribute);

   // if it exists we add it to the array with the position
   if($pos)
   {
      $results[$attribute] = $pos; 
   }
}

// Get the first occuring attribute
$firstOccuringAttribute = array_search( min($results), $results);

// Get the last occuring attribute
$lastOccuringAttribute = array_search( max($results), $results);
```

This could be refactored into something a bit more readable:

```
$uri = 'http://example.com/%sku%/product/%any%';
$attributes = ['%sku%', '%any%'];

$lastAttribute = getLastAttribute($uri, $attributes);
$firstAttribute = getFirstAttribtue($uri, $attributes);


function getAttributeWeighting($uri, $attributes)
{
    $results = array();
    foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        $pos = strpos($uri, $attribute);

        if($pos)
        {
            $results[$attribute] = $pos; 
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

function getFirstAttribute($uri, $attributes)
{
    $attributeWeighting = getAttributeWeighting($uri, $attributes);

    return array_search( min($attributeWeighting), $attributeWeighting);
}

function getLastAttribute($uri, $attributes)
{
    $attributeWeighting = getAttributeWeighting($uri, $attributes);

    return array_search( max($attributeWeighting), $attributeWeighting);
}
```

Comment: This is much simpler if the questioneér wish to add more needles to match for. Should be the answer.